# Python Lambda Dictionary Sort

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below code is sorting according to frequency of values and values are same it sorts the keys in descending order. How does the lambda within sort function work to achieve this?

```
c = Counter(nums)
nums.sort(key=lambda x: (c[x], -x))
return nums
```

```
Input: nums = [2,3,1,3,2]
Output: [1,3,3,2,2]
Explanation: '2' and '3' both have a frequency of 2, so they are sorted in decreasing order.
```

Comment: Please be very clear about what you don't understand. Perhaps provide an example that doesn't behave the way you expected, and explain what you would expect to see instead and why.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist. I am unclear on what (c[x], -x)) in this piece of code.

Comment: Look at a couple of inputs and work it out by hand to build the required intuition. I can't help you if you don't explain your misconception.

Comment: I was unaware that python sorts tuples by looking at elements one by one. Richard's answer helped me get clarity around it. Sure , I would have been able to explain it a little bit more better had I broke it down further. I was trying print elements before and after the sort and trying to understand how it works and was getting stuck. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lambda function:

`key=lambda x: (c[x], -x)`

It could also be written like this:

```
def key(x):
   return (c[x], -x)
```

When sort is called, it sends every element of the list to the lambda function, and uses the result of that function to determine what order the elements go in.  In this case the lambda function takes in a number (`x`) and returns the value of `x` from the counter `c`, as well as the negative version of `x` in a tuple.

```
c = Counter([2,3,1,3,2])
```

Gives us this:

```
Counter({2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1})
```

Now when every element of the original list is called individually against the lambda function, here's what's returned:

```
>>> for i in [2,3,1,3,2]:      
...     print(f"{i}: {key(i)}")
... 
2: (2, -2)
3: (2, -3)
1: (1, -1)
3: (2, -3)
2: (2, -2)
```

The column of tuples that you see is what's being used by the sort function, because of the lambda function.